# 'Invalid module name' creating package with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a project with these contents:

```
proj
├── proj
│   ├── scriptA.py
│   ├── scriptB.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── LICENCE
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

I am following [this guide](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing/) to package this project for PiPY. The `setup.py` file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding=utf8

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = "proj",
    version = "0.2",
    packages = ['proj'],
    install_requires=[],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'scriptA=proj:scriptA',
            'scriptB=proj:scriptB'
        ],
    },

    # metadata for upload to PyPI
    author = "Luís",
    author_email = "luis@mail.com",
    description = "Some package",
    license = "EUPL v1.1",
    keywords = "pip package",
    url = "https://some.place.com",   # project home page, if any
    classifiers = [
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
        "Environment :: Console",
        "Intended Audience :: Science/Research",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: European Union Public Licence 1.1 (EUPL 1.1)",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: GIS"
        ],


    # could also include long_description, download_url, classifiers, etc.
)
```

When I try to build I get the following error:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
error in proj setup command: ('Invalid module name', 'proj')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The build is successful if I directly invoke `python3`:

$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal

The shebang in the `setup.py` is being ignored for some reason.

However, the resulting package [fails to run after being installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325572/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-with-installed-package).